# Error Unclassifiable Statement at (1) in a fortran code for the Archimedes pi problem

Tags: fortran, pi

i'm doing a code in Fortran for the Archimedes aproximation of Pi.
When I compile the code in the Terminal send the Unclassifiable statement error.

This is the code.

```
implicit none

real*8 n,P0,P,F,G,H,I,J,pi,L,x

open(10,file='valordepi.out',status='unknown')

P0=2.d0*(2.d0**(0.5d0))
P=P0

do



n=1,100

pi=acos(x)

x=-1



P(n)=P/2.d0**n

F=-P(n)**2.d0
G=(1.d0-F)**0.5d0
H=1.d0-G
I=(2.d0*H)**0.5d0
J=I*2.d0**n

P=J

L=(J-pi)/pi

write(10,*) n,J,L
end do

close(10)
```

The idea is check the approximation of the Archimedes solution and get the data to do the graphic.
The error is in the line when i wrote n=1,100

Greetings and thanks for the help.

Comment: `do n=1,100` is a single statement and needs to be on one line, or else explicitly marked as continued over two consecutive lines (free-format with &, fixed-format with column 6), not separated by multiple blank lines. However, it will not be a _valid_ statement because do-variable can't be `real` since IIRC 1990. Also you can't use `P` both as a scalar and an array in the same program-unit, or as an array at all without declaring.

Comment: For future such problems, your "Unclassifiable statement error" should give you a line number, telling you which line is unclassifiable.

Comment: Not only the line number but it also often shows the content of that lin. The main message: *Always copy and  paste the complete error output into your question.* More suggestions at: [ask]

Comment: While `do` on its own on a single.line is valid Fortran, the `n = 1, 10` alone on a single line is invalid. It is not anything that the compiler can understand and hence it is "unclassifiable".

Comment: While others have answered your immediate questions, I notice that you're using `REAL` exponents in a number places.  This can have a rather negative effect on the speed of the program.  Where possible, use `INTEGER` exponents, e.g., `F=-P(n)**2`.   To compute the square root, instead of `G=(1.d0-F)**0.5d0` do `G=sqrt(1.d0-F)`

Comment: thanks you all for the reply, i will check it out and tell what was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I check the code several times, and now i got it like this.

```
implicit none
integer n
real*8 P0,P,F,G,H,I,J,pi,L,x

open(10,file='valordepi.out',status='unknown')

P0=2.d0*(2.d0**(0.5d0))
P=P0
x=-1.d0
pi=acos(x)

do n=2,50

P=P/2.d0**n
F=P**2.d0
G=(1.d0-F)**0.5d0
H=1.d0-G
I=(2.d0*H)**0.5d0
J=I*2.d0**n
P=J
L=abs(J-pi)

write(10,*) n,J,L 
write(*,*) n,J,L
end do

close(10)
```

This code don't have errors, and do just what i asked.
Thanks to everyone for the reply.
The error I did was that the `n=2,50` wasn't in the `do` line.